# Combining MEDIAN, IF, ROUNDUP formulas

Tags: excel, if-statement, median, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to find the median value across the C3:AS3 cells, then roundup the result.

C2 is where my formula will be entered. The values I plan to enter in these cells range between the numbers 1-4 (where 1 is ineffective and 4 is effective; I'm an elementary school teacher). I am entering these numbers by hand as the school year proceeds.

So:

1) I would like the formula to ignore blank cells (i.e., prevent C2 to return #NUM! when all or some of my C3:AS3 cells and blank)

2) I would like to find the median results scored through the school year, ranging between 1-4.

3) I would like to roundup the median results.

Am I right to guess that whatever the solution, it will need the IF, MEDIAN, and ROUNDUP formulas? If so... in what order? what formula do I need to create? Thank you in advance for any feedback, much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(ROUNDUP(MEDIAN($C3:$AS3),0),"")
```

Place the above in C2.  Median will ignore blank cells I believe, but will return an error when there are no values.  Roundup will round up all decimals to the next highest integer due to the ,0 for the number of decimal points of accuracy to keep.  IFERROR returns "" when an error occurs in the formula such as all cells being blank.

Comment: I do not know how your worksheet or workbook is layed out, but you can get a lot fancier if you like.  If row 3 is the marks for a particular student, you can make row 4 the next student and so forth.  if you inserted a blank column for C pushing your C3:AS3 over by one and then you could move the above formula to C3 and copy down.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! Oh my gosh, that worked perfectly. Gave it a few tries and BOOM! I'm truly grateful. Thank you. Didn't even know the IFERROR command in excel. Wow.